# Doskey Variable Expansion

Tags: windows, command-line, macros

I'm thinking the answer to this question is no, but it shouldn't be.

From the command prompt normally, the following (as an example):

```
C:\> FOR %I IN (*) DO ECHO %~xI
```

would give me the extensions of all the files in the directory.

I want to use `DOSKEY` to create an alias with the same logic.  e.g.:

```
C:\> MACRO=ECHO $~x1
```

So it would work like this:

```
C:\> MACRO file.js
```

output is

```
.js
```

Obviously I want to do something a little more useful, but I can't get this basic part to work.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a Doskey $1 parameter does not support modifiers like batch parameters and FOR variables.

But you can process the Doskey parameter within a FOR statement and use normal FOR variable modifiers. I use $* instead of $1 so you can supply more than one value.

```
doskey showExt=for %F in ($*) do @echo(%~xF
```

Usage:

```
showExt test.bat test.txt
```

Output:

```
.bat
.txt
```

Comment: Wow!  I'm not sure if this will work with what I need, but pretty GD amazing anyway.  Definitly get the upvote and the answer.